# PHP extensions are installed but not loading - PHP 7.0.9

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to install PHP on Deepin 15.2 (based on debian unstable).

I have **php 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 installed**, but none of the extra extension like:

```
php-curl
php-mysql
php-mbstring
php-mcrypt
```

and many more are loading. Are all installed but none is loaded.

The loaded php.ini is about the same as: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0/php.ini-development execpt for displaying errors.

The command `php -m` only loads:

```
Core
date
filter
hash
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
SPL
standard
xmlrpc
zlib
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: What machine, what software ?

Comment: Are you editing the `php.ini` that your web server uses and not just the PHP CLI `php.ini` file

Comment: @HendraNucleo edited my question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm editing the right php.ini. Phpinfo(); tells me I'm editing the right php.ini

Comment: then check the php/apache server logs. just having a .ini line doesn't mean it actually WILL take effect. if a module can't be loaded, the reason gets logged and the module is simply skipped.

Comment: Can you make sure those extension not commented in `php.ini` ?

Comment: @Marc B, nothing in the error logs except the PHP error that is generated by missing extension like: `Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()`

Comment: @HendraNucleo I've tried to uncomment them, but those are .dll extensions (windows). They are not found. But `apt install php-mbstring` should be enough.

Comment: I mean in your `php.ini`. Not the .dll files.

Comment: Then you have a Windows version of `php.ini` those extensions should have an `.so` extension for a *nix system _not that I am any sort of *nix expert_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well at first there wasn't a php.ini file so I created it and took the one from the source on github (see link). It explicitly says that upcoming is for windows and that linux uses .so but when I changed that it isn't working either. Also the mods-available folder is empty. While apt install php-mbstring tells me it's newest version 7.0.9.

Comment: From line 878(php.ini on github link above), and in your `php.ini` file. Is it started with `;` too? if yes, try removing the `;` and what the result?

Comment: @HendraNucleo No, there isn't I have removed the `;`. And changed the extension too .so but that is not working. The extension aren't loaded, but are installed.

Comment: Restart the apache server ?

Comment: @HendraNucleo done that many times.

Comment: Can you start the chat, this comments seem too long. Like Riggs said above, seems wrong version of php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121281/discussion-between-tim-van-uum-and-hendra-nucleo).

Comment: Hey, i think i found solution. Lemme know if you on.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late response. I have reinstalled my system. Now everything works directly out of the box again. I have no idea what have caused it.

Comment: Now i have problem to connect on local server on guest machine from host browser virtualbox :D